# Why is my Nikon 50mm f/1.8 giving me an fEE error?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, error

I have a AF Nikkor 50mm f/1.8. When I have the aperture setting on the lens to 22 I can take photos. But when I change the dial to anything other than 22(lowest f/stop) then I get a flashing fEE message and r09 where the number of exposure left is.

I don't have the manual for this lens but am just wondering if anyone knows what the issue is here.

My camera is a Nikon D70S.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Must I Lock The Aperture On My AF Lens On My Nikon D40](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/why-must-i-lock-the-aperture-on-my-af-lens-on-my-nikon-d40)

Comment: Sounds like you may need to pay an additional *fee* to Nikon... ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lenses with the aperture ring were originally designed for older SLR's which did not control aperture via the camera body.

Newer SLRs and DSLR control aperture via the body, so these older lenses must be stopped all the way down in order to be used. Your lens is working as it should, and is not defective.

To select aperture using your camera, ensure the aperture ring is set at 22 and shoot in either aperture (A) priority or manual and use the command dial and LCD screen to select the aperture you desire.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem. Its because the lens is "non G" version. The non-G lens have a depth-of-field control. But newer cameras require F22 because the camera controls the depth-of-field.

Great lens by the way.

Regards
  Sigersted

Answer (score 2):

See [my answer here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/why-must-i-lock-the-aperture-on-my-af-lens-on-my-nikon-d40/8256#8256).

TL;DR: the D70s can't read the aperture from the lens ring, it needs to have the aperture locked in a known setting so the body can set the aperture.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above are correct to a point. What you have to do is lock the smallest (in this case, f22) aperture in place using the tiny black slider switch on the right side of the lens (as you view the lens from the top when it is one your camera). That allows the camera to set the correct aperture when you are on auto, and keeps you from accidentally changing the aperture and causing an error message. When you want to control the aperture, as in the manual and aperture priority modes, just move that switch to the unlocked position.

Answer (score 2):

This happens all the time with my D300 and 50mm 1.8. The lens needs to be set on the smallest aperture, typically f/22 on the ring since the camera controls the aperture. There should be a button on the left side of the lens when the back of the camera is facing you, this locks the aperture.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of F EE issue:

1. Set aperture to min f/22 (On the lens)
2. Avoid manual change of aperture (On the lens)
3. Use Body settings to control aperture (On the camera's body)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same lens; use it on my D70.

Answer is really simple -
The camera requires that any acceptable lens be set at the smallest aperture for automatic exposure. The camera will open the aperture as necessary. If you use the manual mode, you won't get the fEE error message at any aperture, but you won't get auto exposure either.