# Why does my camera insist that my Nikon 50mm f1.8 be locked at its lowest aperture setting?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, camera-settings

I just got this lens and I really love it, but I can't seem to figure out why it will only take pictures at f/1.8. If I attempt to change the lens aperture setting, it says the aperture must be set at its lowest setting.  The lens is AF but I can only manual focus on the D3200.  Is there a setting I need to change, or a special way to set up the camera to be able to change the aperture setting on the lens, or is that just how it is for this camera?

Comment: If your lens has an aperture ring you need to set it to f22 and engage the physical slider lock. Then the camera body will control the aperture. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/8345/19059.

Comment: the camera wont let me set the lens to anything but it's lowest setting, 1.8.  If I move the slider on the lens, the camera pops a message saying to set the lens to its lowest setting and it will not work unless I do.

Comment: You rotate the aperture ring on the lens to F22 then lock it in place. Then you adjust the aperture as needed on the camera body.

Comment: not sure which 50mm you have but you can check here if it is compatible with your cam.
http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/compatibility02.htm

Answer (score 1):

@Scott Reed I have the same lens in Nikon F100. In my camera I have always set aperture to f22 in order to be able to set the aperture from the camera. Try to lock the lens in f22. Which exactly 50mm lens, do you have?  Nikkor 50mm 1.8G or nikkor 50mm 1.8D? I am guessing that you have 1.8D which came without auto-focus motor. Moreover, neither the lens nor your camera have got auto-focus motor, thus it's normal that you can't auto-focus.

Comment: The G lens doesn't have an aperture ring. It could be the D or any of several non-D versions of the lens -- none of which have a built in AF motor.