# AF-S NIKKOR 17-35mm 1:2.8D - Viewfinder shows F-- on D3500 with and without locking at highest aperture still shows F--

Tags: lens

Following the advice from here [Why is my Nikon 50mm f/1.8 giving me an fEE error?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/why-is-my-nikon-50mm-f-1-8-giving-me-an-fee-error) I locked the aperture at F22 using the orange lock.

I just attached a this lens to a D3500 camera body, and while the autofocus works well (squaking though), the camera does not seem to detect / allow to control the aperture value when locked at the highest settings F22.

Is this behavior to be expected with this lens/body combination?

Answer (score 2):

**YOU CAN STILL USE THAT LENS IN MANUAL MODE.** Just set the aperture by twisting it to whichever aperture you want, set the shutter speed and ISO manually and have fun. You can get the vibes of an old timey photographer who did not have metering.

That's a pretty good lens. Have fun shooting :)

D lenses will not work on 3000 and 5000 series bodies. They also will not work on the 7500 afaik. These bodies do not have the metering coupling lever. Therefore, you cannot use that lens on that body with any of the automatic modes, even if you move the aperture ring to fully closed position.

AF-**S** *A-B*mm f*X.Y* **D** lenses need metering coupling lever but can autofocus.

AF-**D** *A-B*mm f*X.Y* lenses need AF-Coupler as well to be able to autofocus also.

The lens you have will work on a 7000, 7100, 300, 300s, 500, 750,780,800,810,D3,4,5,6 and a few other bodies that I missed. Basically, 7000 series and above(except 7500).

For more details, take a look at https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm

Answer (score 1):

I read the official manual [Nikon Compatible CPU Lenses](https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/d3500/en/16_technical_notes_01.html#identifying_cpu_and_type_g_e_and_d_lenses) and it seems to be working as intended. Aperture needs to be set manually, and camera metering will not work (it does not).