# Nikon D7000 and Nikkor 28 2.8 is not working together

Tags: aperture, nikon-d7000

Not long ago, my father gave me his old Nikkor 28 f/2.8D lens which seems to be in perfect shape despite being at least 15 years old. The most noticable difference is the aperture ring which non of my G lenses have it. BTW, I own a Nikon D7000.

My Nikon D7000 works fine with my other G lenses. However, it seems to have a problem with the Nikkor 28 2.8 lens; The aperture information is not sent correctly from the lens to the camera. For example when I turn the aperture ring to f/22, the camera's LCD displays it as f/11 and when I turn it to f/8 or wider, it shows f/2.8.

The aperture setting (f6) of the camera is set to "Aperture ring". If I set it to "Sub-command dial", the camera would show a fEE error, so I changed the setting to Aperture ring.

What am I supposed to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your 28/2.8 [a non-CPU lens](https://nikonasia-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7254/~/what-are-non-cpu-nikkor-lenses%3F-how-do-i-use-such-a-lens-on-nikon-dslr-cameras)? (i.e., does it lack the electrical contact via which the lens and camera body talk to each other?) or is it [the AF D version](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/28mm-f28-afd.htm)?

Comment: It is the AF-D version. Sorry, I thought there was only one Nikkor 28 f/2.8.

Answer (score 1):

A correctly-functioning D lens set at the smallest aperture should operate just like your G lenses with the aperture in sub-command-dial mode.  A few things to look at after you put `f6` back at its usual setting:

First, make sure the aperture ring is set at `22` and the aperture ring lock is engaged.  (It's a little switch just below the `28mm 1:2.8D` marking on the barrel.)

Second, check that the camera is getting a good read on what lens is installed.  Install the lens, go to the `Setup` menu, select `AF Fine Tune` and then `Saved Value`.  The screen will show what lens the camera thinks is attached.  If it's wrong, the lens contacts may need cleaning or there could be a problem with the lens itself.

Third, check that the mechanical linkage between the lens's aperture ring and the camera are working properly.  At about the 2:00 position at the edge of the lens mount (looking from the front) is a lever that can be moved by hand.  This is what tells the camera the position of the aperture ring.  Remove the lens from the body, turn the body on and half-press the shutter button.  The display should show `Δf/0` and the number should increase as you move the lever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the aperture ring at the minimum f/22 setting if you want to use the camera controls to set the aperture and avoid the fEE message. See: [Why must I lock the aperture on my AF lens...?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/why-must-i-lock-the-aperture-on-my-af-lens-on-my-nikon-d40)

However, since you have f6 set correctly for aperture ring use and you're getting bad communication, I'd say check that the contacts on the lens are clean. It may be that the lens needs servicing.

Comment: Firstly, I cannot avoid the fEE message because the camera simply cannot receive a "f/22" message from the lens. When I set the aperture ring to f/22, the camera displays it as f/11, as I stated.  Secondly, how do I check that the contacts are clean and if it is in fact dirty, how do I clean them? Thanks.

Comment: _Locking_ the lens at f/22 is different than setting it to f/22. There's a small switch that has to be engaged. Visual inspection should show you if they're dirty. As for cleaning, try dampening a cloth with 99% isopropyl alcohol and gently wiping.

Comment: @inkista, my experience is that setting the aperture to its minimum and locking it *are* the same thing. The lock does nothing but hold the aperture at the minimum.